# Can not have CREATE TABLE inside if else

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run this query

```
DECLARE
      num NUMBER;
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num FROM user_all_tables WHERE TABLE_NAME=upper('DatabaseScriptLog')
    ;

    IF num < 1 THEN

      CREATE TABLE DatabaseScriptLog 
      (ScriptIdentifier VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
       ScriptType VARCHAR(50), 
       StartDate TIMESTAMP, 
       EndDate TIMESTAMP, 
       PRIMARY KEY (ScriptIdentifier)
       );

    END IF;

END;
```

When execute the above, I got the following:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "CREATE" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> begin case declare exit for goto if
>   loop mod null pragma    raise return
>   select update while with       <<    close current delete
>   fetch lock insert open rollback
>   savepoint set sql execute commit
>   forall merge pipe
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: What is your question?  "What does this error mean?",  "Does this mean I can't create a table inside a conditional?",  "How should I do this instead?", etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You cannot run DDL statements like that. You need to use dynamic SQL (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE).

```
IF num < 1 THEN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE DatabaseScriptLog (ScriptIdentifier VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, ScriptType VARCHAR(50), StartDate TIMESTAMP, EndDate TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (ScriptIdentifier))'

END IF;
```

Comment: needs to run in the table space, not straight from what you connect as to run this.

Comment: yes, I am assuming that you and this code are in the schema that you want the table created in (which is usually what you would connect to). This has nothing to do with table spaces, though. Table spaces just define the physical storage location. And you do not have to put it in a stored procedure, you can run this straight from a script file if you want.

Comment: sorry wrong word. I'm in mysql land right now. schema is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this like you could in SQLServer. You need to execute the create code through a stored procedure that is already in the proper schema. You pass the create code as a parameter and the stored procedure that has the correct privileges does it for you.

I use a version script that updates the schema to the latest by running schema altering operations separated by if-then clauses to check what version the db is at. After altering it increments the version so that the next if statements test passes and so on. If you are up to date and run the script the ifs skip all altering code. If your db is at version 46 and you run the script which has all changes up to 50, you execute only the blocks that represent versions 47-50.

You could execute immediate but would need elevated privileges which I would not recommend.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We need privileges to run DDL statements.  In order to run them in PL/SQL (anonymous block or stored procedure) we need the privileges granted directly to our user, not through a role.  But EXECUTE IMMEDIATE does not require any additional privileges of its own.